# Calculate the sum of values replacing NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with some NaNs in column B.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A':[654,987,321,654,987,15,98,338],
    'B':[987,np.nan,741,np.nan, 65,35,94,np.nan]})
df

    A   B
0   654 987.0
1   987 NaN
2   321 741.0
3   654 NaN
4   987 65.0
5   15  35.0
6   98  94.0
7   338 NaN
```

I replace NaNs in B with the numbers form A

```
df.B.fillna(df.A, inplace = True)
df


    A   B
0   654 987.0
1   987 987.0
2   321 741.0
3   654 654.0
4   987 65.0
5   15  35.0
6   98  94.0
7   338 338.0
```

What's the easiest way to calculate the sum of the values that have replaced the NaNs in B?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`series.isna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) with [`.loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to filter the Column A which meets the condition that column `B` is null and then sum:

```
df.loc[df['B'].isna(),'A'].sum()
```

Alternative:

```
df['B'].fillna(df['A']).sum() - df['B'].sum()
```

Note: you should do this before doing the inplace operation or preferable create a copy and save under a different variable for later reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try the function `math.isnan` to check the NaN value.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math 



df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':[654,987,321,654,987,15,98,338],
        'B':[987,np.nan,741,np.nan, 65,35,94,np.nan]})


    for i in range(0,len(df['B'])):
        if (math.isnan(df['B'][i])):
            df['B'][i] = df['A'][i]

    print(df)
```

Output :

```
  A      B
0  654  987.0
1  987  987.0
2  321  741.0
3  654  654.0
4  987   65.0
5   15   35.0
6   98   94.0
7  338  338.0
```